# Return a value to one function from another

Tags: php, function, return, return-value

I have 2 functions in PHP and i want to `return` a value to one function to another. this is my functions

```
 public function save_payment_log_data($icasl_number, $exam_session) {

$paylog_av = $this->payment_log_exists($icasl_number, $exam_session);

}


function payment_log_exists($icasl_no, $exam_session) {
        $this->db->where('icasl_no', $icasl_no);
        $this->db->where('exam_session', $exam_session);
        $query = $this->db->get('exm_paymentlog');
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $pl = $query->row();
            $pay_id = $pl->paylog_id;
            return $pay_id;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I want to return `$pay_id` to the `save_payment_log_data()` function but in here $pay_id didn't return to that function. I think it's return from the function `payment_log_exists()`
so how can I return `$pay_id` to the  `save_payment_log_data()` function

Comment: so what's the actual question?

Comment: @rtfm question updated. I want to know how to return that value to `save_payment_log_data()` function

Comment: Try  var_dump($paylog_av);  under $paylog_av = $this->payment_log_exists($icasl_number, $exam_session);  and check what is the result.

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe, you are already using `return`. It should return value...

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju It didn'nt return to `save_payment_log_data()` function, value returns from payment_log_exists() function

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe, is it going to else part??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju some times

Comment: when you call the payment_log_exists(), you should either get the pay_id or false. print $paylog_av to see whats coming back

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe, if condition is true, u ll get value. If its false, u ll not get values.

Comment: @sampathwijesinghe - You're already returning values. Do you expect it to return $pay_id every time?

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju ok ok I now it mate .but the reason is  Its not returning the value I'll check.

Comment: Please modify your question to say, why you're not returning $pay_id . That will essentially mean, that query variable returned <=0 or, most possibly 0. So, verify if you have the records in the db for  'exm_paymentLog'

Answer (score 2):

See this example it's working fine:

```
function save_payment_log_data() {

$paylog_av = payment_log_exists();

# print the return value
echo $paylog_av;

}

function payment_log_exists() {
        return "Hello";
    }

save_payment_log_data();
```

You can try to remove `public` and `this` form `save_payment_log_data()`,
and call the `save_payment_log_data()` function where you want.

Answer (score 0):

your are only assigning a value to the $paylog_av your "save_payment_log_data" function should be:

```
public function save_payment_log_data($icasl_number, $exam_session) {

$paylog_av = $this->payment_log_exists($icasl_number, $exam_session);
return $paylog_av;

}
```